# Create a javascript src attribute with a value written in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, src, dynamically-generated

I'd like to dynamically generate a javascript src attrbute with a value written in an input.

I've tried this method:

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="name" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#name').keyup(function() {
    $('#display').text($(this).val());
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var filename = ' <a id="display"></a> ';

  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + filename + ' "></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
```

Do you know why the src attribute isn't correctly written within the html file ?

Thanks :)

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src=" <a id=" display"=""></a>  "></script>` is what gets inserted. How exactly should this even look like? Please, describe the process of entering a URL and inserting the script tag in detail. I can’t really follow what your intent is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to achieve something like this. here is the fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/4mcej5fk/

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
<a href="#" id="display"></a>


$('#name').keyup(function() {
    $('#display').html($(this).val());
  });
```

> to change href attribute you can simply do

```
 $('#name').keyup(function() {
    $('#display').attr("href",$(this).val());

  });
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qswur2bz/

Comment: yes it works, however I'd like using the value of this input as a variable to be inluded in the src url.

Comment: @KinguPrima check the fiddle. I have updated the answer,